# Does new approve call overrides previous approved tokens?

Tags: solidity, erc-20

Let's say I asked a user to approve the `X Dai` amount today for Smart invoice asking price.

```
daiContract.methods.approve(cAddress, X.toString()).send({
    from: ethereum.selectedAddress
});
```

But, he buys after a week since the time he approved. so, the asking amount increases with the time `Y Dai` so, he has to approve extra dai amount
`Z Dai = Y Dai - X Dai`

```
daiContract.methods.approve(cAddress, Z.toString()).send({
    from: ethereum.selectedAddress
});
```

but it is overriding the previous `X Dai` amount and giving some random amount when I check the allowance

```
daiContract.methods.allowance(ethereum.selectedAddress,cAddress).call({
        from: ethereum.selectedAddress
    }
```

so, what happens when I approve multiple times and does it add like if I approve `X Dai` first-time transaction and then `Y Dai` second time approves the transaction = `X Dai + Y Dai`? or it completely overrides the first and now only `Y Dai` is approved?

Comment: You should read [this ERC20 approve issue in simple words by SmartDec](https://blog.smartdec.net/erc20-approve-issue-in-simple-words-a41aaf47bca6).

Comment: thank you it helped me to under approve function and it's vulnerability.

Answer (score 1):

Each `approve` method in ERC20 token standard rewrites the previous approved amount. Method `transferFrom` is decreasing the approved amount on each transfer. For example if I approve my someone to spend 1000 of my tokens, but then for some reason I wan't to decrease that amount to 300 I will just call `approve` method again and pass amount 300 as parameter (1000 now will be replaced by 300). If I wan't to fully disable this someone to manage my tokens I will pass 0 as parameter.